# How to make Ant build fail if standard out or error contains a warning?

Tags: ant, build

I have an Ant-based build worked on by multiple developers. I want to discipline the team by causing a hard build break if any part of the build pipeline emits a warning.

Realistically, I think the build needs to fail if either stdout or stderr contains a regex along the lines of `"\bwarn(ing)?\b|\berror\b|\bfatal\b"` where the `\b`'s are word boundaries.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to control the output of the build, you will need to implement a custom listener. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html for more information. Once implemented, you can instruct Ant to use your listener by passing `-listener fully_qualified_listener_classname`, assuming the class is added to the classpath.

Basically you need to implement `org.apache.tools.ant.BuildListener` and do your logic in the `messageLogged` method which receives a build event corresponding to a log generated by a task. The event contains the message to be logged which you can parse to determine whether to stop the build, typically by throwing a runtime exception like `BuildException`.